# Python/Pandas: Unique table transpose and transform

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel table like the one below, where the number '1' marks in which bucket a given store falls under.

```
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
|       |       |           |     H    |     H    |      N     |     G    |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
|       |       |           |    111   |    114   |     120    |    130   |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| Group | Code  | Name      | Bucket 1 | Bucket A | Bucket Min | Bucket B |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| H     | 11110 | Store 1   |     1    |          |            |     1    |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| N     | 11450 | Store AAA |          |          |      1     |          |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| H     | 11152 | Store BBB |          |          |      1     |     1    |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
| H     | 11734 | Store XXX |          |     1    |            |          |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+
```

I would like to transform this table to something like what I have below.

```
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Category | Number | Transfer   | Received Information                              |
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| H        | 111    | Bucket 1   | Received for Store 1 (11110)                      |
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| H        | 114    | Bucket A   | Received for Store XXX (11734)                    |
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| N        | 120    | Bucket Min | Received for Store AAA (11450), Store BBB (11152) |
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| G        | 130    | Bucket B   | Received from Store 1 (11111), Store BBB (11152)  |
+----------+--------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

How can this unique transpose and transform be done in Python/Pandas?

Note that the text 'Received for' will always appear at the beginning of each cell in the 'Received information' column.

Comment: Hi there, how far did you get in solving this? Can you post the part of the code you are stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give it a try. First, you should make the excel file from which to read the data more pandas-friendly, by adding an extra line for the names of the columns and properly naming the rows:

[image]

Following that, this code should give you the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
f = r"path/to/file.xlsx"


# %%
df = (
    pd.read_excel(f, index_col=[0, 1, 2], header=[0, 1, 2])
    # move away from multi-index
    .reset_index()
    # create a new column combining Code and Name
    .assign(NameCode=lambda x: x["Name"] + " (" + x["Code"].astype(str) + ")")
    # drop the columns we combined into the new one above
    .drop(columns=["Name", "Code"])
    # 'transpose' table to create one entry for each of the NameCode
    # entries
    .melt(id_vars=["Group", "NameCode"], value_name="deliveries")
    # drop everything with NaN
    .loc[lambda x: ~x["deliveries"].isnull()]
)
print(df)

# %%
pvt = df.groupby(by=["Category", "Number", "Transfer"]).agg(
    Received_Information=pd.NamedAgg(
        column="NameCode", aggfunc=lambda x: "Received from " + ", ".join(x.str.strip())
    )
)
print(pvt)
```

```
   Group           NameCode Category Number    Transfer  deliveries
0      H    Store 1 (11110)        H    111    Bucket 1         1.0
7      N  Store XXX (11734)        H    114    Bucket A         1.0
9      N  Store AAA (11450)        N    120  Bucket Min         1.0
10     H  Store BBB (11152)        N    120  Bucket Min         1.0
12     H    Store 1 (11110)        G    130    Bucket B         1.0
14     H  Store BBB (11152)        G    130    Bucket B         1.0
                                                          Received_Information
Category Number Transfer                                                      
G        130    Bucket B      Received from Store 1 (11110), Store BBB (11152)
H        111    Bucket 1                         Received from Store 1 (11110)
         114    Bucket A                       Received from Store XXX (11734)
N        120    Bucket Min  Received from Store AAA (11450), Store BBB (11152)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first part of the code works fine, but the second shows an error. It seems that you call a `pd.NamedAgg` attribute that doesn't exist: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'NameAgg'`. As a second question, what exactly does the `aggfunc=lambda x` portion of the code do?

Comment: You  need to update your pandas version - `NamedAgg` was added in version 0.25.0 I believe.
The aggfunc combines the "Store 1(11110)" etc. strings, and adds "Received from " to the beginning of each combination. It's the string aggregation of the `groupby` pivoting.

Comment: Alternatively you could also use this code for the second part (without `NamedAgg`):
`df = df.drop(columns=['Group']);
pvt = (df.groupby(by=["Category", "Number", "Transfer"])
       .agg(lambda x: "Received from "+", ".join(x)    )
)`

Comment: The error came up even though I'm using pandas '0.25.3'. In any case, the alternative work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I looked at your error message again - you have a typo there: it should be `NamedAgg`, not `NameAgg`.

Comment: Thanks for double-checking!